# Generating different random numbers given same boundaries

Tags: c#, random

I'm writing a program that randomly generates a quantified item list for a magic shop.

I have a function that is supposed to generate bounded random quantities depending on the rarity of an item.

```
public int SetItemQuantity(string Rarity)
        {


            if (Rarity == "Common")
            {
                Random rndQty = new Random();
                int commonQty = rndQty.Next(5, 10);
                return commonQty;
            }

            if (Rarity == "Uncommon")
            {
                Random rndQty = new Random();
                int uncommonQty = rndQty.Next(0, 5);
                return uncommonQty;
            }
            else
                return 0;
```

The problem is that when this function is later called in a loop and I have two items of the same rarity, they consistently return the same quantities.

Comment: The duplicate should answer your question, but I thought I'd just check that you understand that your two calls to `.Next` are returning numbers from 5 to 9 and from 0 to 4 respectively? Is that what you're expecting or was it from 5 to 10 and 0 to 5?

Comment: Duplicate answered my question and code now works as expected, thanks!

Comment: So you needed 5 to 9 and 0 to 4?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help!